Jump to contents page with epub.js
A user can upload a epub file which, after the user provides a few options (like whether they want it rendered continuous or not) I open and display with epub.js. Together with the epub in the web page I provide a few buttons that allow the user to do things like page forwards and backwards through the epub.
I was wondering how I could have a button which changes the location to the contents page for the epub. Searching tells me that I can jump to a page using
book.goto(some_cfi)
or
rendition.display(some_cfi)
but I'm not sure what a cfi is nor if there's any way for epub.js to know the cfi for the contents page (if it even exists) is nor can I currently get it to do anything.
How can I create a button that jumps to the contents page in a epub file display with epub.js?

A CFI is a Cononical Fragment Identifier - Summed up: It's a standardized method for identifying content within an Epub. You can learn more about them here: https://idpf.org/epub/linking/cfi/epub-cfi.html
To answer your question, yes, you can navigate to a specific page of an Epub by using the rendition.display(cfi) method. The only catch is that you will need Epub.js to process the locations of the entire book within the book.ready event. This specific event isn't documented very well in Epub.js but it will be fired once the book is downloaded and parsed. Check out the locations example file on line 73 from Epub.js:
book.ready.then(function(){
    // Load in stored locations from json or local storage
    var key = book.key()+'-locations';
    var stored = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (stored) {
         return book.locations.load(stored);
    } else {
        // Or generate the locations on the fly
        // Can pass an option number of chars to break sections by
        // default is 150 chars
        return book.locations.generate(1600);
    }
})

The book.locations.generate() method will generate what you can consider a list of "pages" as epubCFIRanges (It will be an array of strings). The value passed to the generate method tells Epub.js how many characters should be equal to 1 "page" but it defaults to 150 so it might be wise to provide a value for this calculation like in the example.
After you have the CFI Locations parsed and stored in memory or localStorage or whatever you choose, you can then take any of those epubCFILocation strings and pass it to the rendition.display(cfi) method and the epub should display the appropriate content.
Again, for this to work as designed, you will need to have the entire book downloaded and parsed by Epub.js. The generate method will only work properly if the entire book has been parsed.
I hope this helps.
